# The image failed to upload.on a server laravel

Tags: laravel, image, file, deployment, crud

**The image failed to upload.**

link
https://comedoruniversitariouncp.000webhostapp.com/products/create

The project works in local server,
the error appears when i upload to a server

**create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('products.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" step="0.1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Amount</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
```

**ProductController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image'
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');

        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

        Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'image' => $new_name
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('message', 'Product created successfully');
    }
```

Comment: What is the error>

Answer (score 6):

As you mention about works on local but not remote. I assumed that the `upload_max_filesize` is greater than the size your upload file, and both on local and remote are not the same.

Comment: Exactly. This error is returned from Validate function, in my case i resolved changing value of variable upload_max_filesize on php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

Try with adding `mimetypes` in validation of image.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');

        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

        Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'image' => $new_name
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('message', 'Product created successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use The  `Storage` `Facade` as a convenient way to interact with your local filesystems.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
//...
$new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('images', request->file('image'), $new_name);
//...
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files)

Answer (score 0):

You Should Try code this,

you may change a part code :

```
$image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
```

to be code :

```
$image->move(public_path('images'.$new_name));
```

this is code, 100% work to me.